# Bitwise '&' operator in chained comparison

Tags: python, comparison, bitwise-operators

```
var = 86
print((var < 90) & (var >= 80))
```

prints `True`.

But why do all these print `False`?

```
print(var < 90 & var >= 80)
print(var < 90 & (var >= 80))
print((var < 90) & var >= 80)
print(var < 90 & True)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a bitwise operator to perform a boolean operation?

Comment: Try replacing `&` with `and`; what you're doing doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I know I am suppose to use  'and' operator. I just wanted to know why these were giving False.  @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the `and` operator instead for boolean operations.

Since python supports chaining relational operators (i.e. you can use `0 < var < 100` instead of `0 < var and var < 100`) and processes binary operations (i.e. addition, subtraction, bitwise operations, etc.) *before* relational operators due to operator precedence, all of the failing cases you posted actually mean something else.

1. `var < 90 & var >= 80` is equivalent to `(var < 90 & var) and (90 & var >= 80)`
2. `var < 90 & (var>=80)` is equivalent to `var < 90 & True` for which look at the 4th case.
3. `(var<90) & var>=80` is also similar to the 4th case (this resolves to `True & var >= 80` which will then resolve to `0 >= 80`).
4. `var < 90 & True` is equivalent to `var < (90 & True)`. The implementation of the `&` operator is designed to return `0` if either one of the operands is not an integer (which is another one of the biggest pitfalls of dynamic typing), which is why all such similar statements resolve to `var < 0` which is false.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Take `print( var<90 & True)` as an example,

`print( var<90 & True)` is equivalent to `print( var < (90 & True))` and hence it gives False.

However if you put in parenthesis in the right place, i.e. `print( (var<90) & True)`, then it will give True.

Comment: Which operator will be executed first ?

Comment: This document not include any `priority` definitions. I ask `a>>b & c<<d >e < f` meaning what ? Basic math got `*,/,+,-` priority  order but where priority  of operators ?

Comment: @dsgdfg In the documentation, it says "The following table summarizes the operator precedences in Python, from lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most binding). Operators in the same box have the same precedence."

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Kong !

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise operator `&` has higher precedence than the comparison operators, so the `90 & var` is evaluated first, and then a chained comparison takes place.

```
>>> var = 86
>>> var<90 & var>=80 # var<90, and '90&var' is greater than or equal to 80
False
>>> var<(90 & var)>=80 # same as above
False
>>> (var<90) & (var>=80)
True
```